# Auto-scroll or Auto-focus on CakePHP Form button

Tags: cakephp

I can't believe I'm asking such a trivial question but I actually don't know how to search for this..

I have a simple form built using the CakePHP Form Helper and stylized using Bootstrap. I have a button that when clicked, reloads the same page with the value in a div tag updated. However, the page reloads (as its meant to) and positions itself at the top of the page. So, it's rather annoying to have to scroll down every time this button is clicked. How do I reload the page, but if its loaded via the button click, then auto-scroll or "focus" to the DIV that was just updated or even the button itself?

Is it a simple HTML or CSS fix, or do I need to get into jQuery and the like?

Comment: just add "#id-of-the-div" at the end of the url..it will auto scroll to div position.

Comment: If you update per Ajax call and use a anchor tag as the trigger, a simple and nifty trick is to set the href attribute to either `#0` or `javascript:void();`. But if I understand your question correctly that's not your situation. But it is within the scope and is just a nice trick to remember :)

Comment: Thanks Vicky, works a treat!

And also to you Jelmer! The project involves a fair bit of Ajax so I'm sure this too would come in handy eventually. :-)